# JavaScript Framework with HTML 5 and ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, frameworks

What would be a suitable JavaScript Framework with HTML 5 (with fallback) project and a ASP.NET backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try telerik [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)

There are some samples [here](http://kendouiaspnetsamples.codeplex.com/).